# target class inside the current selected class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm researching about CSS3 flipping-card layouts. There's a lot of samples in CodePen but they include unnecessary clutter. I've managed to get the 'bare-bones' version, but I can't target the specific card. I thought of adding ids but selecting them in JS would require some string manipulation, and I think this is overkill and there's a simpler way that I'm missing.

This line is the problem:
`$('.card_container>.card').toggleClass('flipped');` I want to say "select `.card` under this current `.card_container` that I'm clicking".

Codepen: https://codepen.io/reiallenramos/pen/bYWKyv

```
$('.card_container').on('click', function () {
  $('.card_container>.card').toggleClass('flipped'); #help me change this line
});
```

--

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: tomato;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 2px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.card_container {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.card {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  div {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

  &.flipped{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

--

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card_container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">flip</div>
      <div class="back">one</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">flip</div>
      <div class="back">two</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">flip</div>
      <div class="back">three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">flip</div>
      <div class="back">four</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this changes into your jQuery codes, every-time when you click `.card`, jQuery `this` keyword toggles class on that clicked element and not on all `.card`.

```
$('.card_container > .card').on('click', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```js
$('.card_container > .card').on('click', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: tomato;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 2px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.card_container {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.card {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  div {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
    
  &.flipped{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card_container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">flip</div>
      <div class="back">one</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">flip</div>
      <div class="back">two</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">flip</div>
      <div class="back">three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">flip</div>
      <div class="back">four</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```